# Animating the Border of a TextBox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to test out a concept for a loading animation, but I have no idea where to start. Basically, I have a text box that is filled in automatically with some JavaScript on the page, but it can take a few seconds to load. I am looking for a way to put something resembling the IE11 indefinite-time progress bar inside it. It would be like a bar about 1/2 of the width of the box and only a few pixels in height that animates across the box. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this in a way that will work in all major browsers (including mobile)?

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle with your code?

Comment: @Daniel: i suspect there is no code yet.

Comment: have you considered an animated .gif image? Works better than css+javascript.

Comment: Yeah... There isn't much code to show right now; it's just an input tag (with type set to text). I can make one if you want, though ;)

Comment: @WasabiFan Nah, it's cool. But when you mean "Animating", do you mean like an infinite loop of going from left to right until reaching the end and then repeating or?

Comment: @MilchePatern, that might work, but the bigger question is how would I put said gif in to the box in a reliable way that scales correctly? That's the part that I am stuck on...

Comment: Wasabi Fan, most of the comunity is here to 'help' you, not to 'do it for you'. If you cannot show what you have tried so far, demonstrate a basic understanding of your situation, your question is most likely to be downvoted, see closed. Perhaps what you need is a good tutorial about html design or a nice 'do it for me plugin'? Try studying around jquery-ui. It's been designed to achieve some front-end design and animation.

Comment: @DanielLisik Exactly like that. Just to show that it's doing something...

Comment: @WasabiFan Is it necessary to animate the border? Can't it be a div positioned right above the input field?

Comment: @DanielLisik It doesn't have to be the border; as long as it's inside the field. Something like my sample image will work fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VRaaF/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, hope that it helps you in the right direction (and I hope you don't mind using some jQuery):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="loading_bar"></div>
    <input type="text" value="" id="input">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#input { 
    width:296px; 
    padding:2px;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left: 0;
    border:1px solid #ddd; 
    margin:0; 
    z-index:1;
}

#container { 
    position:relative;
    background:#ddd;
}

#loading_bar { 
    width:0; 
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#00f; 
    height:4px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function to_zero(){
    $("#loading_bar").css({'width':'0'});
}

function to_max(){
    $("#loading_bar").animate({'width':'300px'}, 2000);
}


setInterval( function(){to_zero();to_max(); }, 2200);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zrfQn/3/)

Comment: Wow; thanks! It works on my phone and I'm guessing it will work on the desktop; I can check in an hour or so. It'll need a bit of modification, but now I know all of the CSS that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers render borders statically;

About animating the border of a TextBox (presuming input:text or textarea) cross-borwser AND cross-platform is impossible. For a lesser scoped of browser, per say, modern browsers, there is css-level3 with `border-image`.

But it will be painfull.

About displaying a progress bar upon a TextBox, it will be quite easier, especially if your content is loaded via AJAX. It's all about a container displayed position absolute left top. Then the css animes the container.

See jquery-ui or search the net for 'animated progess bar'

Answer (score 0):

I've always done 2 spans. You have one as the wrapper, with 100px. Then, As the % of loading, you just have the other span being x pixels wide.

You could then make a setTimeout function to keep the animation going. Slowing adding pixels until the inside span is as wide as the wrapper span.

This should load very fast.